# Git commits not reflecting on GitHub activity graph and Contribution activity

Tags: git, github

I have been facing an issue with my GitHub activity graph and Contribution activity not updating despite making commits to my repository. Here's the scenario:

Three days ago, I successfully committed changes to my Git repository using the terminal(mac), and the changes were uploaded to GitHub. However, even after multiple commits since then, my GitHub activity graph has not been updated. Strangely, the commits I made a few days ago are still listed as the latest activity.

Previously, when I committed using the same method, the changes were promptly reflected in the activity graph.

Things I've checked/tried so far:

Commit History: I can see the commit messages and changes in the local repository using git log.(for three days ago)

GitHub Repository: The files are indeed updated on GitHub, but the activity graph doesn't reflect these recent changes.

Pushing Changes: I have used git push after each commit to ensure that changes are pushed to GitHub. push origin main command.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Any suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+count+contributions

Answer (score -1):

after some investigation, I found a solution that resolved the problem for me.
Open your terminal and run the following commands, replacing "username" and "yourmail@example.com" with your GitHub username and email:

git config --global user.name "username"
git config --global user.email yourmail@example.com

then:

git commit --amend --reset-author

This process ensures that the author information is correctly set for the latest commit.